# Alpine apk add --repository upgrades other packages

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, package-managers

We use an alpine 3.9-based docker image with no Python3 on it. This is the list of packages we currently install:

```
apk add --update --no-cache \
  bash \
  curl \
  findutils \
  git \
  mysql-client \
  make \
  nmap-ncat \
  openssh-client \
  openssl \
  patch \
  procps \
  python \
  sshpass \
  sudo \
  jq \
  wget
```

I'm now trying to install a specific version of Python3 (3.7.5) from alpine 3.10 main repository, using:

```
apk add --no-cache python3 --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/main
```

However, this ends up upgrading other packges that are not dependencies for Python3:

```
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/5) Upgrading readline (7.0.003-r1 -> 8.0.0-r0)
(2/5) Upgrading bash (4.4.19-r1 -> 5.0.0-r0)
Executing bash-5.0.0-r0.post-upgrade
(3/5) Replacing python2 (2.7.16-r1 -> 2.7.16-r1)
(4/5) Installing xz-libs (5.2.4-r0)
(5/5) Installing python3 (3.7.5-r1)
Executing busybox-1.29.3-r10.trigger
OK: 258 MiB in 91 packages
```

Why does this happen?

On the other hand, if I add a tagged repository `@future http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/main` to `/etc/apk/repositories`, and attempt to do:

`apk add python3@future`, I get this:

```
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  bash-5.0.0-r0:
    masked in: @future
    satisfies: world[bash]
  python2-2.7.16-r1:
    masked in: @future
    satisfies: world[python]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not 100% familiar with apk but I bet the beginning of your output is dealing with dependencies where it probably shows you how they are resolved. Since you install/update some packages with newer version, if they also need up-to-date dependent packages, those will be upgraded as well.